# Como fazer paginação no SQLServer 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Testei com duas formas, mas não obtive exito.

```
select * from table OFFSET 10 ROWS

select top 10 * from table OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Curiosamente eu nunca precisei utilizar offset nessa versão do SQLServer, e agora estou tendo dificuldades com algo relativamente simples.

> **Erros exibidos no console:**
>
> Mensagem 102, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 3
>    Incorrect syntax near
>   'OFFSET'.
>   Mensagem 153, Nível 15, Estado 2, Linha 3
>   Invalid
>   usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

**Posso estar equivocado,** mas confesso que não encontrei respostas no site que realmente respondessem a minha dúvida (o que é curioso, já que é algo relativamente simples).

Comment: Quero estar enganado, mas acredito que o LIMIT não funciona no SQLServer. Este é um comando do MYSQL, não é? Eu pelo menos utilizo TOP 10 no SQLServer, e LIMIT 10 no MYSQL.

Comment: As construções que utilizou somente funcionam na versão 2012 (em diante) do SQL Server.

Comment: Vide "Comparing performance for different SQL Server paging methods" https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2696/comparing-performance-for-different-sql-server-paging-methods/

Answer (score 2):

Há duas maneiras de fazer isso. Vamos assumir que a consulta que você irá fazer é esta:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >= '1980-01-01' ORDER BY OrderDate
```

Neste caso, voce deve determinar o total de resultados usando:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >= '1980-01-01'
```

...pode ser inapropriado considerando a eficiência do resultado.

Agora, para conseguir realizar uma consulta mais adequada, o seguinte modelo poderia ser o mais eficiente:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY OrderDate ) AS RowNum, *
          FROM      Orders
          WHERE     OrderDate >= '1980-01-01'
        ) AS RowConstrainedResult
WHERE   RowNum >= 1
    AND RowNum < 20
ORDER BY RowNum
```

Aqui irá retornar 1-19 linhas da query original.
Agora, só adaptar ao seu código.

Answer (score 1):

Thiago, Para paginar é necessária uma ordenação (**ORDER BY**) dos registros para o seu caso:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY 1 --Nome campo
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Cheguei a testar utilizando order by também, mas recebo os seguintes erros:

Mensagem 102, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 3
Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
Mensagem 153, Nível 15, Estado 2, Linha 3
Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Comment: Thiago, não esqueceu do ORDER BY? pois os Offset é um parametro adicional do ORDER BY. Segue doc da microsoft com a documentação da funcção [link] (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql)

Comment: Tentei sim!
A query que tentei rodar foi essa: SELECT TOP 10 * FROM users 
ORDER BY id
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY

Comment: Continua nao funcionando!
SELECT * FROM PessoaFisica 
ORDER BY pf_id
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY

Antes mesmo de rodar a query, já é apresentado "erro de sintaxe", as palavras sublinhadas em vermelho...

Comment: O banco está com nível de compatibilidade?

Comment: Pra ser sincero eu nunca tinha acessado a propriedade, e pra variar eu não sou o SA do banco... Mas isso implica em que?

Comment: Então na documentação da microsoft estava escrito a partir do SQL 2008 mas ao ler o documento mais a fundo, a função de Offset está disponível a partir da versão 2012 do SQL server. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql#Offset